# Do people have different reactions to biting insects from different regions?

Tags: bugs, bites

I grew up in the U.K., but I moved (aged 34) to German three years ago.

I fully understand that this may be solely my personal experience, but biting insects seem to affect me more strongly here than in the U.K. The bites seem to last longer, and they itch more.

Do insects in one locality differ from the same insects (or their close cousins) in another locality in their effect on people? That is to say would a mosquito bite from the U.K. and Germany affect me differently?

("Locality" is admittedly qualitative and vague.)

Comment: Different species of mosquito?

Comment: I have definitely heard that the answer to this question is yes, but I don't know if there was any true scientific basis. It also matches with my experience, which is that I get very small bumps or no bumps at all from my local mosquitoes, but when I go on vacation I often get large, very itchy bumps that last for days.

Comment: @csk it could be related to what your body is reacting to, and if it’s more or less used to that particular allergen. Or if there are particular ones you’re more sensitive to. But that’s an unsourced pondering, not any kind of answer

Comment: It might depend on the parasites being carried by the insect. For example malaria is caused by a parasite in the mosquito, but in UK there is no malaria parasite.

Comment: Are you drinking lots more beer now that you live in Germany? [This](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2020-02-11/mosquitoes-attracted-to-some-more-than-others/11950616) source says that beer and bannanas increase your attractiveness to mosquitoes.

Answer (score 2):

Over at this other question (Link: [Is it possible to develop immunity against mosquitos?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4310/is-it-possible-to-develop-immunity-against-mosquitos)), a couple of other people seem to share similar experiences, and they discuss some articles regarding developing resistance towards mosquitoes by exposure.

My personal experience is also similar to yours, and given that there are several thousand different species of mosquitoes in the world, it's not unreasonable to think that adapting to one species wouldn't necessarily protect you from another one, but it's difficult (for me at least) to find any clear scientific evidence backing it up.

Comment: Is it adjustment to the local bugs or are the local bugs biting in a different way? I got bitten a lot in Norway but non of the bites stayed more than a day, while at home the results can last for a week or even longer.

Comment: @Willeke I think both? People seem to get used to their local variants, and if a variant you're not supposed to be used to gives you smaller bumps, then that's probably something about how your body reacts to that specific bug